# CodeIgniter Framework PHP: Set up bootstrap twister after install via composer

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am wondering about bootstrap installing into codeginiter 3.0.

First, i'm install bootstrap twbs via composer. And then it's stored in vendor folder.
I have run the grunt code JS by command line and nothing happen. Just some file not related with bootstrap.

How can we set up the bootstrap to assets folder by composer. Any one in here have use it. Thank a lot.

Comment: The post you give me. It for the laravel framework. I have used it before. In laravel, bootstrap is load very easy. But in CI, it a issued :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer for myself. When we run the CLI GRUNT. It have the default folder call *dist* or *dest*, we just replace it with the destination to assets folder or public folder.

Thanks for watch and answer.

Comment: similar when use bower or another tool manage dependencies :)